# Default database schema used by entity manager

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

In the spring boot application. I don’t want to specify the scheme in the database connection url. I set the default database schema via spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=myschema, as a result, when executing SQL code, the request is executed in the public schema

```
try (Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)) {
            Query<MyClass> query = session.createNativeQuery(sqlText, MyClass.class);
            entityList = query.getResultList();
     }
```

If you set a breakpoint:

in

```
session.getSessionFactory().getProperties().get("hibernate.default_schema");
```

everything is correct - myschema
but

```
session.doWork(con -> System.out.println("current schema: "+ con.getSchema()));
```

returns null

The problem is solved by setting the schema manually

```
session.doWork(connection -> connection.setSchema("myschema"));
```

How can we get around this, how can we force the default database schema from spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema to be used for this case?